# Switch behavior when new enum values are added

Tags: swift, healthkit

*Note: this is no longer relevant. Recent versions of Swift have multiple features that address enum binary compatibility in various ways, such as `@unknown default`, frozen enums, etc.*

Various enums in HealthKit tend to get new values added with each release of iOS. For example, [`HKWorkoutActivityType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutactivitytype) has had new values added in each iOS version since its introduction.

Say I am mapping this enum to a string value using a Swift `switch` statement:

```
extension HKWorkoutActivityType {
    var displayName: String {
        switch self {
            case .americanFootball: return "American Football"
            // ...Exhaustive switch statement, with a line for every enum case.
            // Including values added in iOS 10 and 11...
            case .taiChi: return "Tai Chi"
        }
    }
}

let event: HKWorkoutEvent = ...
print("Activity type is: \(event.type.displayName)")
```

This switch statement, compiled against the iOS 11 SDK, works fine and is backward compatible with older iOS versions. Note that at the time of compilation, the switch statement is exhaustive, so there is no `default` case.

But if new HKWorkoutActivityType values are added in iOS 12, and I don't recompile this code, how will the `displayName` getter behave for new enum values? Should I expect a crash? Undefined behavior? Does it depend on the type of enum (for example, here it's an Objective-C `NS_ENUM`, but will Swift enums behave differently)? etc.

Comment: This is heavily discussed at present, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md (and the links to the swift-evolution mailing list therein).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for mentioning that proposal, I had forgot about it. The proposal says "The Swift 4 program will trap at run time if an unknown enum case is actually encountered" - that may be the answer to my question.

Comment: Please add that "unknown default" edit as an actual Answer to this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, this is the partially what [this Swift Evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md) is addressing. 
Hopefully they will decide on a solution that satisfies issues like this nicely too!

Long story short, you may be able to avoid this issue by adding a default case, (even though the compiler will yell at you), or using version tags. However this problem likely falls under "undefined" currently.

The long story:

The current version of Swift does not have ABI stability, so a compiled Swift application is *not guaranteed to* (and almost definitely wont) interface with a Framework compiled with a newer version (the reason the platform Frameworks are still Objective-C).

So how this category of changes affect Swift is a work in progress. We will probably have a better definition of how to deal with this type of issue when Swift 5 is released. until then adding default and/or version checking is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**Very**  interesting question, and upvoted. I know of no way to *perfectly* test this in (a) Xcode 9 and (b) iOS 11. But that may be your answer.

I think the *desired* solution if `if #available(iOS 12, *)`, where though is at issue. Encapsulate the entire switch statement? Just the iOS 12 addition?

The result *should* be that between the target iOS version in Xcode and the Swift compiler, it's covered - and should yield an error (hopefully explaining the issue that iOS 11 is targeted but something is only available in iOS 12) to indicate you either need to use (a) the `if #available(iOS 12, *)` someplace or change your target.

I know of no easy way to test this though, without rebuilding. Which is integral to your question! Therefore I guess the rule is:

**Always rebuild your app when a new iOS (and associated Xcode) version is released.**

Consider this part of you taking ownership of your code.

Comment: Sure, updating apps in a timely fashion is of course the best solution. But even if you promptly release an updated app to the App Store, a user may not update the app immediately - so the scenario discussed here is always going to be a possibility.

Comment: I totally agree. I thought before making this an "answer". While not really an answer, (1) I really don't know what would be, and (2) it works better than a mere comment. The truth is IMHO that a developer can only do so much... take ownership, test, use the betas ASAP, keep things updated... and from there it's the user/consumer who needs to take ownership. If *your* app aborts because *you* didn't do your job, that's on you. But if there's an app update out there and the user is using an old version? That's on them....

Comment: If it's your framework/enum (or something from a third party, which at that point you do have the option of not using) that's broken... absolutely, it's not only on you but I seriously doubt it will build! If it's Apple? They do a pretty good job of this. WWDC introduces such things (along with a new version of Xcode) that won't be out for a few months. And in that new/beta version of Xcode (which the new/beta OS target can only be used) you can't build either. You asked a very good question - in theory. (Thus, my up vote.)